# Inheritance vs. getattr & setattr

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Suppose we wish for `A` to inherit `B` - can do via `class A(B)`. However - what about below?

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        b = B()
        ismagic = lambda x: x.count('__') == 2
        nonmagic_attrs = [attr for attr in b.__dir__() if not ismagic(attr)]

        for attr in nonmagic_attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, getattr(b, attr))
```

`A` now has all of `B`'s attributes and methods, minus magic - effectively, inheritance. ... or is it? Are there problems with above implementation? Application context & minimally-reproducible example below.

---

**Context**: conditional inheritance; I seek for `DataGenerator` to inherit either `NumpyGenerator` or `HDF5Generator`, but *not* both. This can be done via an external conditional upon two classes, each implementing one inheritance - but that's unelegant and duplicative. Thus, a single-class, wrapper-less implementation is desirable.

Also, no class utilizes static methods, class methods, wrappers, or strictly private methods.

---

```py
class DataGenerator():
    def __init__(self, gentype, **gen_kwargs):
        self.a = 1
        self.inherit_datagen(gentype, **gen_kwargs)
        self.print_info()
        print(self.a)

    def inherit_datagen(self, gentype, **gen_kwargs):
        if gentype == 'numpy':
            datagen = NumpyGenerator(**gen_kwargs)
        elif gentype == 'hdf5':
            datagen = HDF5Generator(**gen_kwargs)

        ismagic = lambda x: x.count('__') == 2
        nonmagic_attrs = [attr for attr in datagen.__dir__() if not ismagic(attr)]

        for attr in nonmagic_attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, getattr(datagen, attr))

class NumpyGenerator():
    def __init__(self, a=2):
        self.a = a
    def print_info(self):
        print("Am Numpy")

class HDF5Generator():
    def __init__(self, a=3):
        self.a = a
    def print_info(self):
        print("Am HDF5")

dgen_numpy = DataGenerator('numpy', a=6)
dgen_hdf5  = DataGenerator('hdf5',  a=9)
```

```py
>> Am Numpy
>> 6
>> Am HDF5
>> 9
```

Comment: It would be much easier to explain to new team members to only inherit one or the other than it would to explain the voodoo involved in your first approach. When would someone inherit both?

Comment: @Sayse Inheritance is the greatest "voodoo" I know of in Python. Your question's answered in 'context': each class is fairly lengthy, so rewriting is undesired.

Comment: Seems like `DataGenerator` should be the base class and `NumpyGenerator` and `HDF5Generator` two derived classes.

Comment: Or use composition instead of inheritance, where you pass either the NumPy or the HDF5 implementation details to an instance of `DataGenerator`, for example when creating it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Your former suggestion is neat, eliminating the rewriting component - though still leaves need for a `return class` via `if else`. Perhaps this isn't too bad, I'll give it a go - thanks for noting. As for 'composition', unsure how that'd work, but will consider it also. -- Regardless, am still interested in the original question